# Pronunciation of variable with subindex

Tags: pronunciation

This question is about pronunciation of variables with a subindex such as $P_i$.

In this [Stanford video lecture on statistical mechanics](https://youtu.be/MCRHXHskWnE?t=13m33s) $P_i$ is pronounced "
Pees of i" and $E_i$ is pronounced "Ees of i". Is this pronunciation standard in the US? In Europe I have just heard "Pee i" and "E i".

Comment: The lecturer is likely saying "P sub i" with "sub" being short for subscript.

Comment: Yes, Susskind is definitely saying "$P$ sub $i$" and that's standard in the US.  For superscripts, it would be "$P$ super $i$."

Answer (score 2):

Most of my lecturers say "P of i" and that's how I say it as well. But I've heard "P sub i" many times.